# Какой скрипт отвечает за регистрацию пользователей в joomla 1.5

Tags: joomla, php

Сейчас занимаюсь интеграцией sharetronix + joomla и возникла проблема передачи "непросоленого" пароля. Где находятся скрипты отвечающие за регистрацию пользователей в joomla ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`/components/com_user/controller.php`**

**`/administrator/components/com_users/controller.php`**

и папки "`views`" и "`models`" там могут быть интересны.